# when support of createOrUpdateNotebookShares function in NoteStore will available for C++ SDK.?

Tags: evernote

I checked in the C++ SDK official GitHub repository of Evernote **createOrUpdateNotebookShares**  function in NoteStore is not available till now.
when this support will come for c++ SDK.

Comment: Hi Ajit. That SDK hasn't been updated since 2013 (!). If I were you, I would assume it's obsolete and unsupported, and will not receive any further updates. You could always look at how some of the more recent SDKs implement this function and copy/paste into a pull request, but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for the Evernote Developer Platform team.